# jQuery ajax call image loading

Tags: jquery, ajax

I wonder if any of you guys knows how to show an ajax loading image on a jQuery $.ajax call, only if that call is taking more that a specific time. Thanks for any help!
cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Throbber can solve your issue: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/throbber

It's a jQuery plugin that handles Ajax loading animations and it has this option - you can set the delay.

Or you can set the delay manually using setTimeout() before displaying loading animation.